# Characterization of piecewise continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

Are there functions that are (a) piecewise continuous over each bounded subinterval of [0,∞) yet not (b) piecewise continuous over [0,∞) ?

I cannot see how (a) and (b) are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most setting, when we say $f$ is piecewise continuous, we mean we need to be able to write the domain of $f$ as a **finite** disjoint union of intervals such that $f$ is continuous on each of these intervals.

If I define, for example, 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{n^2+1}\text{ for } n\leq x < n+1$$
this clearly satisfies (a), as we can divide any bounded interval into finitely many intervals on which f is constant. But on $[0,\infty)$, we cannot obtain a finite number of intervals on which $f$ is continuous.

If it were possible, one of these intervals would have to contain $(a,\infty)$ for some $a$, but 
$$f:(a,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$$
is not continuous on this interval.

Comment: Thank you, the bold **finite** made the point clear.